# застрял в bootcamp

Tags: windows, macos, mac, apple

Установил Windows 10 на mac через bootcamp, а теперь не могу из него выйти. В винде через bootcamp выбираю "перезагрузить в OS X", а меня возвращает в винду. Как вернуться в OSX и снести эту проклятую винду?

Comment: Может быть во время загрузки системы зажать Alt?

Comment: я пробовал, но тогда выходит только 1 диск - Windows, то есть выбора по сути нет
в общем я бы с радостью снес все-все-все, но не знаю как

Comment: Что показывается в Disk Managment , стандартной оснастке Windows ? Есть там диск OS X? там должно быть 3 партиции: EFI, основная, и Recovery

Comment: там ТОЛЬКО windows, но при этом у винды 94 гб, а все остальные тогда где непонятно. То есть их просто не видно. Но зато почему-то есть bootcamp (зачем он если "нет" OSX).
А Вы не знаете, можно ли как-то отформатировать ЖД и переустановить OSX, не выходя из WINDOWS?

Comment: Я буквально не давно в целях тестирования хотел с помощью BootCamp "убить" OS X. Мне Yosomite этого не дал сделать. Возможно Вы лезли руками через hex-редакторы и сами поправили сектора. Либо запускали сторонние средства бэкапа или переразметки или просмотра диска.

Comment: ничего такого не делал, к тому же где тогда 400+ гб, если они не на винде, а OSX нет?
А можно как-то винду снести и посмотреть что будет?

Comment: При попытки выйти на внешний диск через bootcamp открывается темный экран с движущейся эмблемой аля thunderbolt - чтобы это могло значить?
Я уже все перепробывал, но похоже это безвыходная ситуация - неужели я испортил свой MAC так сильно?

Comment: 1) Нет. Не испортили. Каждый кто купил легально, имеет возможность накатить систему OS X повторно. Вам кстати должны были выдавать его при покупку. Ну или позвоните в apple-сервисный-центр. 2) Возможно Вы проворонили мои слова. Еще раз. Загрузитесь в Windows, который Вы поставили в BootCamp. В его оснастке Disk Manager выпишите все разделы. Погуглите как должно быть и сравните с тем что есть!

Comment: Расскажите, как восстановили-то?